# How can I configure sourceCompatibility and compilerArgs for all modules, java, android application and android library?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to see lint errors in the console and I want to configure to use java 7 just once instead of every module (we have 12 modules).

I put this into my root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation,unchecked"
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        targetCompatibility = 1.7
    }
}
```

and it does work for pure java projects (`apply plugin: 'java'` in its own `build.gradle`) but not for `com.android.application` and `com.android.library` modules.

I assume there is some more general "filter" than `withType(JavaCompile)` I would have to use but I can't find it. Gradle scripts are still magic to me. Poking around I tried `JavaCompile`'s super class `AbstractCompile` but that didn't do the trick.

How can I avoid having to add

```
android {
    …
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.7
        sourceCompatibility 1.7
    }
}
```

for the Java version and whatever it would take for the compilerArgs to every Android module?

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it should do the trick for both `Android` and `Java` project.

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation,unchecked"
            sourceCompatibility = 1.7
            targetCompatibility = 1.7
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The only difference with OP question is "projectsEvaluated" call, will it do the magic?

Comment: It should work. Android prevents the access to the `compileJava` task. Adding `gradle.projectsEvaluated` fixes that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and report back.

Comment: Did it help you ?

Comment: Haven't had time to try it yet, but I guess it should work. Unfortunately I'm not the author of the question, I just submitted a bounty for it. I hope he'll see this and accept if it's OK with him.